# May 2013 Gmail app update: "Reply as" multiple accounts gone? (Android 4.2.2)

Tags: email, gmail, google-account

I have two gmail accounts hooked up to my Samsung S4. When I go into the Gmail app and compose an email, I'm given the choice to send as any email address associated with either account. It used to be that I could reply to any email from any address as well.  So for example, if someone sends something to my work address I could reply to them from my personal address just by selecting the account from the pull down at the top.

Now it looks like I can only reply, reply all, or forward an email from any email address associated with that one account.  So I can only reply from my work addresses if the email was sent to a work address; I can only reply from my personal addresses if the original email was sent to one of my personal addresses.

This seems like a major loss of functionality!  Especially when Android will "share" from the last email account touched, it seems important to be able to quickly select which address to reply from / send from.

Can anyone explain this behavior?  Is this a problem for anyone else?  Is there a way around this?  Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you only do that on iOS and desktop according to their help page.